# Jira labels in/not in

Tags: label, jira, jql

I'm using epic theme, script runner and labels to filter team boards. 
But, when I add another teams label to one of the returned Jira's I want it to be removed from that teams board and only appear on the other teams board.

The below code works fine:

```
project = (ABC)
AND (
    "Epic Theme" in (team-A)
    OR 
    issueFunction in issuesInEpics("\"Epic Theme\" in(team-A)")      
    OR 
    labels in (team-A, some, random, things) 
)
```

If I add a label of **'team-B'** to one of the returned jira's then it also appears on team B's board as expected, but I also want to remove it from team A's board, so tried the below query which has no affect:

```
project = (ABC)
AND (
    "Epic Theme" in (team-A)
    OR 
    issueFunction in issuesInEpics("\"Epic Theme\" in(team-A)")      
    OR (
        labels in (team-A, some, random, things)
        AND
        labels not in(team-B, team-C, team-D) 
    )
)
```

i tried a few variations also including `labels != 'team-B'` but with no luck.
any ideas or is Jira not going to bend this way?